# Replace multiple characters in a text file using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have to convert a PDF file into database file. The PDF file has a Unicode subset font. I converted the file successfully into a text file using the code format. I used a stream reader in vb.net.

How can I replace the whole file by reading and replacing the characters? The complete file is encoded and **I want to decode it by replacing each character with my specified characters**.  I need replace multiple characters in the text file using vb.net and in fastest way possible because I need to do this on 40,000 files.

Answer (score 0):

I would use word object to declare the file and use

```
With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = "hi"
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.Text = "hello"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, _
    Wrap:=wdFindContinue
End With
```

`.text` is the text you have in your word document and `Replacement.Text` is the text you replace with.

Comment: this isnt a text message - you should spell out the words for those who do not speak English as their first language.